# duplicate entry error after adding google services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I wanted to add firebase to one of my app.  I integrated  firebase according to  firebase offical documents. but  when I tried to "run" app. it gives me this warning

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzc.class

I removed all the firebase coding & removed it from  gradle file. but error still exist untill I remove this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but unfortunately I need google services to work with  firebase.  here is  my app gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 15
        versionName "2.01"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/main.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.commit451:NativeStackBlur:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.11.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is my project gradle file

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show both of your build.gradle files entirely?

Comment: I updated the question with both build.gradle files

Comment: Do you have this class inside same jars?

Comment: actually I figured the problem. problem was with facebook audience network

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was  with Facebook Audience network.  once I excluded google services it worked fine.  If anyone  having   same problem  change your audience network dependency like this

```
   compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.11.0'){
     exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
 }
```

Comment: @APP Bird, Could you please look at the issue, I am not finding in which third party I have to exclude. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40492785/4675067

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Add these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android{
....
    packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }

}
```

to your app's gradle file.

Comment: it didn't solved the problem. still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add Firebase related dependencies

And Firebase related dependencies under dependencies in the same build.gradle file.

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'                        // this line must be included to integrate with Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'                   // this line must be included to use FCM
}

Update services using com.google.android.gms:play-services

If you add Firebase into an existing project which uses any function of gms:play-services, such as gps location,
you have to update their versions, too. Upon writing this tutorial, 9.2.0 works well. If you get compilation problems, you need to check find out the correct version number.

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'

Source:
https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb