# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

Tags: android, exception, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Below is the error I am getting after adding the Firebase, google services in gradle and google-services.json in app module.

I have 13 modules in my app. I have 7 build variants in all the modules. I tried with placing the google-services.json in app module and placing it in build variant folder inside the app module. I am getting same error. I have the notification feature in one build variant.

I removed the firebase related code in gradle and google-services.json from application, it is working perfectly.

Due to security reason I can't share the entire file.

Main app module gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
       transitive = true;
   }
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
   apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
   compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.7'
   apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.0.7'
   compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

In Application gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForSmePreDebug FAILED
>       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForSmePreDebug'.>
> ```
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

I reffered many links in StackOverflow for this issue. None fixed my problem. Any suggestions appreciated.

**Edited** push notification module gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
   //compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0') {
      //exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
   //}
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might because you have duplicate dependencies. One has latest version and the other one has old version.

What you can do is

1. check your app dependecies.

   ```
   ./gradlew clean :app:dependencies
   ```
2. find 3rd party libraries that also have com.google.android.gms included.
3. exclude this group from the library

   ```
   compile ('library') {
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' 
   }
   ```

This might be able to be a quick fix. But it's not good!

The best solution should be updating your 3rd party library, their latest version might update their google services library already.

Comment: I already checked with this solution, it didn't work. Once again I will check and update you.

Comment: the exclude group method didn't work for me either. But did you try the last one? Update the party or force the version of the conflict library? This one fixed my issue.

Comment: I edited my question please see it. I tried yours and not working for me. This is gradle dependency i am using in the project. I tried and not able to find the version conflict in gradle. Could you please help to find?